# Porting a unicode enabled Delphi 2006 application to Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2009

I have an application which is fully unicode compatible in Delphi 2006. I had replaced all AnsiStrings with WideStrings, replaced all VCL controls with TNT controls, and changed all string functions from AnsiStrings to WideStrings. It looks like all that work was for nothing, because I'm going to have to reverse it all. Is there anyway to Trick Delphi 2009 into thinking Widestrings are in fact UnicodeStrings?

Comment: By the way, feel free to accept an answer here.....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there really isn't. But you won't regret the work to truly Unicode enable your application.

The TNT controls can easily be replaced with the regular VCL controls.  You can do that pretty simply using the wizard from GExperts (http://www.gexperts.org) that replaces one control type with another automatically.

Then, you can change all your WideString declarations to regular strings.  String is now an alias for UnicodeString, and so all your strings can hold Unicode data just fine.

BTW, the author of the TNT controls, Troy Wolbrink, now vastly prefers Delphi 2009 over his own controls.

Comment: And if I might say, that some of the best resources out there for converting your code to unicode delphi are the white-papers written by some guy named nick.  Also, there's a pretty good book by Marco Cantu, that covers the conversion in depth.    There are a lot of reasons, and there's a lot of pay-back to be had in enabling your application to go to native Unicode delphi.  I've done it for at least a dozen major apps.

Answer (score 0):

Main advantage of TNT Controls is only that It can work as Ansi program in Windows 9x. It is not full unicode. If you want full unicode support everywhere (such as Stringlist.LoadFromFile, Form.OnKeyPress) it's good to move to Delphi 2009.

Comment: I even replaced stringlists everywhere with WideStringLists. Are text files unicode in Delphi 2009? I replaced text files with Filestreams.

Comment: You can load unicode text with widestringlist, but you can not load text from file with non-ansi file name, as simple as you did it with ansi file names.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing in an application that used different XML files as input.  In my case, I was working with UTF-8 (so we could use regular strings) throughout the program and only converted to WideString for display purposes (TNT controls).

I removed the conversions back and forth between WideString and UTF-8 and replaced the TNT controls with regular VCL controls by hand since there were only a handful of forms.

The conversion took about an hour with testing.  The code is simpler and the program is noticeably faster.